# M2 - How to get active fitters using observer

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3.4

How to get active filters using observer on product listing page, what is the procedure to get that?

Answer (score 1):

**You can call event `catalog_product_collection_load_before` on listing page**

**you can get active filter like this :-**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$stateFilter = $objectManager->create('\Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State');
$selectedFilters = $stateFilter->getActiveFilters();
foreach($selectedFilters as $filter){
    echo $filter->getName(); // Color etc
    echo $filter->getLabel(); // Black etc
}
```

Comment: Where i can put the above code?

Comment: create event catalog_product_collection_load_before

Comment: can you pls join the chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119033/m2-how-to-get-active-fitters-using-observer

Comment: Shall i put log for what attributes selected using  echo $filter->getName();

Comment: Where i can add your code?

Comment: can you pls join chat?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119033/m2-how-to-get-active-fitters-using-observer

Comment: I  just post my whole observer, can you pls check it.

Comment: I just add log, it is not paste on the system.log, any help thanks "$this->logger->info(print_r($activeFilters, true));"

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119033/m2-how-to-get-active-fitters-using-observer